# adding attachment to gmail app with intent

Tags: android

I have an application which open pdf file with tap on app (default PDF in raw folder), openwith (myapp) and also from mail attachment. I converted the selected PDF file into inputstream and then to bytearray. Now I have a button and when user click on it need to send email through gmail app using intent. I need to add inputstream or bytearray as pdffile to the mail as attachment.I used the following code I can see the attachment with no bytes and received email donot have attachment. Struggling from more than 10 hours.. please help...

```
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sample@gmailcom"));
                sendIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "sample@gmail.com" });
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testPDF");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is a PDF ");


                File fileIn = new File(name, "myfile.pdf");
                Toast.makeText(this, fileIn.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Uri fileuri = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileuri.toString()));

                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried many ways and finally found a solutions myself. Use file provider to attach the file to mail without storing it physically on the device. The code is follows and hope it helps someone else.
Add a class AttachFileProvider with below code
    public class AttachFileProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String CLASS_NAME = "AttachFileProvider";

```
// The authority is the symbolic name for the provider class
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.pDoc.pdocsigner.provider";

// UriMatcher used to match against incoming requests<br />
private UriMatcher uriMatcher;
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    // Add a URI to the matcher which will match against the form
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "*", 1);

    return true;
}


@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri,  String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Check incoming Uri against the matcher
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        // If it returns 1 - then it matches the Uri defined in onCreate
        case 1:
            // The desired file name is specified by the last segment of the path
            // Take this and build the path to the file
            String fileLocation = getContext().getCacheDir() + File.separator + uri.getLastPathSegment();

            // Create & return a ParcelFileDescriptor pointing to the file
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(fileLocation),  ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
            return pfd;

        // Otherwise unrecognised Uri
        default:
            //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Unsupported uri: '" + uri + "'.");
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unsupported uri: " + uri.toString());
    }
}

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Not supported / used / required for this example
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s, String[] as) { return 0; }

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] as) { return 0; }

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) { return null; }

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) { return null; }

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String s, String[] as1, String s1) { return null; }
```

}

to attach the mail use the following code.

```
 if (bytes.length > 0) {
            try {
                createCachedFile(this, attachmentFileName, bytes);
                this.startActivity(getSendEmailIntent(this, "tomailid", "Test", "See attached", attachmentFileName));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gmail is not available on this device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

public  void createCachedFile(Context context, String fileName, byte[] content) throws IOException {
    File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + fileName);
    cacheFile.createNewFile();
    BufferedOutputStream bostream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFile));
    bostream.write(content);
    bostream.flush();
    bostream.close();
}

public static Intent getSendEmailIntent(Context context, String email, String subject, String body, String fileName) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //Explicitly only use Gmail to send
   // emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    //emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/email");
    //Add the recipients
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { email });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    //Add the attachment to custom ContentProvider
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + AttachFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + fileName));
    return emailIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you attachment file can be read by gmail app, so put it in the external sdcard storage area. Maybe you path has problem, change it and test.

Comment: If there is sdcard storage area in the device, it wont work... so I am trying to do it within memory